# how to apply restrictions to which items are selectable in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, view, model, combobox

I am developing a c# winforms application. The underlying model has, among other things, a StartTime and an EndTime DateTime property, with the restriction, that the StartTime must come before the EndTime. To give the user the ability to change these properties, I fill two comboboxes with sample values to choose from, and hook each combobox up, so that selecting another value will change the corresponding property in the model.

The problem with this approach is that it allows the user to try to select an illegal value. Ideally, I would like it that when a user selects a certain StartTime value, the possible EndTime values are capped, so that it is not possible to select EndTime values earlier than that. One way to achieve this would be to fill the end combobox with the new legal values, and then select what was there previously. This would require that my SelectedIndexChanged event handler was temporarily shut off, since otherwise reselecting the EndTime would cause an infinite loop, alternating between filling/reselecting the StartTime and the EndTime comboboxes, respectively.

Another solution would to keep all the sample values, and then revert any illegal changes the user tries to make, but the fact that the user can try to select illegal values doesn't appeal to me. I am not fond of having to disable an event handler temporarily, since it doesn't seem clean, but I cannot see any better solutions. Do you have any suggestions or improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a combobox selection is changed, do this:

1. Set a flag variable which you can use to prevent re-entry into the event handler for this combobox (A), and
2. Reload the other combobox (B) with all legitimate dates, considering the new date just selected in this combobox (A).
3. Set the date in the other combobox (B) to the date that was already selected (before the dates were replaced), if there was a date selected in (B) and if it is legal with the new date in combobox (A)
4. Reset the flag.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class (some would call it "ModelView") designed specifically for your UI scenario.
It is sort of a proxy between data model and UI. The purpose of the proxy is to maintain invariant (startDate < endDate) during editing deferring changes to the model unti editing is done. At that moment changes are applied to the underlying data object.

```
      class MyDataObjectProxy: IPropertyChangedNotification
      {
          MyDataObjectProxy(MyDataObject model)
         {
             _model = model;
             _editedStartDate = model.StartDate;
             _editedEndDate = model.EndDate;
         }


          MyDataObject _model;

          public DateTime StartDate
          {
             get
             {
                 return Math.Min(editedStartDate, editedEndDate); 
             }

             set 
             {
                 _editedStartDate = value; 
                 RaisePropertyChanged("StartDate");
                 RaisePropertyChanged("EndDate");
             }
          }  

          public DateTime EndDate
          {
             get
             {
                 return Math.Max(editedStartDate, editedEndDate); 
             }

             set 
             {
                 _editedEndDate = value; 
                 RaisePropertyChanged("StartDate");
                 RaisePropertyChanged("EndDate");
             }
          }  


          DateTime _editedStartDate;
          DateTime _editedEndDate;


          public void ApplyChanges()
          {
               DateTime start = StartDate;
               DateTime end = EndDate;

              _data.StartDate = start;
              _data.EndDate = end;
          }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this solves my problem. It seems that with your approach, users are able to temporarily create illegal values, and then apply changes, when they have a legal Start/End pair. I want to make it impossible for them to accidentally choose illegal values. And if I just refuse to apply illegal changes, I still have the problem of my comboboxes displaying what the users have chosen, not what my model says.

Comment: @Boris, What does "Illegal values" mean in the context of editing? The public interface of MyDataObjectProxy always maintains invariant - legal combination of values.

Comment: ..Continued: And then her selection could be reverted. I cannot see how your approach would help here, but please tell me, if I misunderstood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One time you open your form you:

1. Set **StartDate** to some initial value, let's say today
2. Set **EndDate** to some initial value, let's say tomorrow (disabled)
3. Add global `boolean` variable `bool SilentInvoke = false;`
4. Subscribe to `SelectedIndexChanged` for Start and End UI controls.
5. In beginning of every selectedindex changed event have code more or less like this:

   ```
   if( SilentInvoke)
   {
         SilentInvoke=false;
         return;
   }
   ```
6. User changes **StartDate**, enable **EndDate**.
7. User changes **EndDate**, if it's before **StartDate**, notify to the user and reset it to initial value, but before make `SilentInvoke=true;`

There is always a possibility that user goes back and changes **StartDate** again, but you have to have somewhere validation method that validates the data before final request.

First you give a user kind of guide ( start enabled, end disabled), after leave user free to decide and make validation before actual request.

Comment: Thanks. This is along the lines of showing the user every possible value, which i wanted to avoid. I also don't like to restrict my user so that they have to change the StartDate first, if all they want to do is change the EndDate. But I might use some variation of the SilentInvoke variable.

Comment: Nothing bad to make disable fist EndDate, which gives to user some natural guideline:'define start and after define end'.

Comment: But setting the StartDate and EndDate is not a one-time thing in my application. The user might change her mind later on and decide she wants a later EndDate. In that case, I would not want her to have to re-select the first StartDate, before being allowed to select the EndDate, that would not be a natural interaction.

Comment: That's why I say: give a guideline only first time, if you wish, this, by me, doesn't create non coerent UI behaviour. The final choice is up to you.